# What's wrong with my zenity dialog? selector is not extending vertically

Tags: arch-linux, openbox, zenity

zenity list dialog looks different after a system upgrade,

`%> zenity --text "Select" --list --column="Profile" --list a b c`

[image]

Any idea on the extra space in the dialog? The selector should extend to its maximum size vertically. (It doesn't even if I resize the dialog)

I'm running `zenity 3.8.0` in openbox (Arch Linux package `zenity-3.8.0-1`)

Comment: Looks normal to me. You mean the space between the selector and the ok button?

Comment: @jordanm yep, the selector is not extending vertically

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my system (Zenity 3.4.0) and given how it appeared for you after an upgrade it's likely a regression. This is not a solution to the actual problem here but you might want to check out [yad](https://code.google.com/p/yad/). It's an advanced Zenity fork with a lot of interesting new features. You might be able to make it backwards compatible to Zenity with [this tweak](https://code.google.com/p/yad/wiki/ZenityWrapper).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bug in zenity 3.8.x ([Bug 702535 - List box doesn't expand to fill window](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=702535) ) which was fixed in 3.10.2 ([commit](https://git.gnome.org/browse/zenity/commit/?id=80bc8ce643979fec201c4ebd5cd6405b6310357f)). Current version in Arch Linux (3.12.1) works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is gtk3-3.10.1-1  ( gtk3-3.10.2-1 too)

Downgrade to gtk3-3.8.4-1 until they patch it, if they do it.